# Determine whether integral converges or diverges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\infty}_{0} \dfrac{1}{\mathrm{e}^x+\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x $

$0$ and $\infty$ makes the problem confusing. Can someone show me how to solve it?

Comment: compute at first the indefinite integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0 and $\infty$ makes the problem confusing. Can someone show me how to solve it?

There is no problem in $0$. If you're only interested in divergence/convergence, you can try using convergence tests or criteria.

However, direct computation is possible (and easy!) too and that doesn't only give you convergence, it also gives you the value:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,\mbox{d}x=\lim_{p \to \infty}\int_0^p \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,\mbox{d}x
=\lim_{p \to \infty}\int_0^p \frac{e^x}{1+\left(e^x\right)^2}\,\mbox{d}x$$
Now take $u=e^x$ to get $\arctan e^x$ as a primitive function.

Answer (score 1):

It does, for any $b>0$,

$$
\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}dx
=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}dx
=\arctan{(e^{b})}-\arctan{(1)}
$$

Now just let $b\rightarrow\infty$ to get the value $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

the indefinite integral is $$\int\frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx=\int\frac{e^x}{(e^x)^2+1}dx$$ and Substitute $$t=e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Te only problem is  at $\infty$. If you only want to know whether it converges, you can use asymptotic analysis: we have:
$$ \frac1{\mathrm e^{x}+\mathrm e^{-x}}\sim_\infty\frac1{\mathrm e^{x}}=o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr)$$
and $\;\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm d x}{x^2}$ converges, hence $\;\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm e^{x}+\mathrm e^{-x}}$ converges.